# In Objective-C where is code executed when I haven't specified a thread anywhere in my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I notice that I see behavior indicative of multi-threading even when I never explicitly use GCD or any other mechanisms to do things off the main thread. Why does this happen and what can I know or guess about my program behavior in cases where only some of my statements give directions about what thread should be used? Where should I have read about this that I haven't seen it?

Comment: Please update your question with some specific code examples.

Comment: "*I see behavior indicative of multi-threading even when I never explicitly use GCD*".... such as? You're probably just mistaking the effect that the main thread's run loop creates with background threading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default (if you don't use any concurrency APIs), almost all of your code will run on the main thread. This thread is managed by a [run loop](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html), the understanding of which may be a big part of what you're looking for.

The exceptions are documented on a case-by-case basis in Apple's documentation, and in order to get good information on SO about them, I would suggest posting a specific example of your code, what you expect, and what you specifically observe that has you thinking that it's happening on a different thread. As an FYI, you can see what thread your code is running on when you pause on a breakpoint, in the Navigator panel's Debug pane.

Comment: Just about anything with a "completion block" will likely execute the completion block in a background thread.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't know if my experience matches this. Especially when you consider that UIView animation's completion block is one of the most ubiquitous examples and it runs on main thread.

Comment: OK, maybe I should have said any completion block outside of UIKit.

Comment: @rmaddy That resonates quite a bit more :-) Though case-by-case reading is highly recommended. For example, NSURLConnection's delegate methods are called on the same thread from which the connection was instantiated.